# "IndexError: too many indices for array" for 1D numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Somehow I do not understand the error message I am getting:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I have looked into other questions with that title but none seem to apply to my situation.
This is my code.

```
import numpy as np


def revert_array(array):
    max_len = len(array)
    ret = np.array(max_len)
    for i in range(1, max_len):
        ret[i] = array[max_len - i]
    return ret


a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
r = revert_array(a)

print(r)
```

I do give only an integer value as the index. What am I missing?

Comment: this line `ret = np.array(max_len)` causes error. However, I am not sure about logic of your function, so I can't tell how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
ret = np.array(max_len)
```

is not returning the desired empty array, because of that you are getting this error

This should work

```
import numpy as np


def revert_array(array):
    max_len = len(array)
    ret = np.zeros(max_len)
    for i in range(1, max_len):
        ret[i] = array[max_len - i]
    return ret


a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
r = revert_array(a)

print(r)
```

Output

```
[0. 4. 3. 2.]
```

Another way to create empty array in numpy

```
ret = np.empty(shape=(max_len))
```

Here you are trying to reverse the input array, but above logic has some problems, below code should reverse the array

```
import numpy as np


def revert_array(array):
    max_len = len(array)
    ret = np.zeros(max_len)
    for i in range(0, max_len):
        ret[i] = array[max_len - 1 - i]
    return ret


a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
r = revert_array(a)

print(r)
```

Output

```
[4. 3. 2. 1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as anuragal answers, if you pass an integer to `np.array`, an array of that length is not created. For that, you have to use something like `np.zeros` or `np.empty` and pass in an array shape (which in your case, is simply one integer, so a 1-D array will be created). Always read the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) to understand how functions work.

Secondly, since it seems like you are trying to reverse an array, (the hard way, using loops!) `numpy` arrays start with the index 0: so you need to run that loop starting at zero.

Thirdly, if reversing this way is not purely out of academic interest, `array[::-1]` does the job. How does it work? Read this document on [indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).